# Convert 2d Array in to Needed format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I need to convert the below 2dimentional array into specified 2d array format. Array contains the id followed by multiple parent and multiple sub category fields array. Also, I have tried to convert the code, but am not getting the expected output.

This is the code what i have tried,

```
   $a1 = Array
    (
  '0' => Array
     (
        'hits' => Array
            (
                 
                    '0' => Array
                    (
                        'product_code' => 1003,
                        'in_stock' => 1,
                        'category_ids' => Array
                            (
                                '0' => 1,
                                '1' => 2,
                                '2' => 1596,
                                '3' => 3820,
                                '4' => 3821
                            ),
                        'categories' => Array
                            (
                                '0' => 'Category',
                                '1' => 'Groceries',
                                '2' => 'Home & Kitchen',
                                '3' => 'Stationery',
                                '4' => 'Party Accessories'
                            )
                    ),
                    '3' => Array
                    (
                        'product_code' => 1004,
                        'in_stock' => 1,
                        'category_ids' => Array
                            (
                                '0' => 1,
                                '1' => 2,
                                '2' => 1596,
                                '3' => 1597,
                                '4' => 1598
                            ),
                        'categories' => Array
                            (
                                '0' => 'Category',
                                '1' => 'Groceries',
                                '2' => 'Home & Kitchen',
                                '3' => 'Kitchenware',
                                '4' => 'Cookware & Non Stick'
                            )
                    ),
                    '2' => Array
                    (
                        'product_code' => 1003,
                        'in_stock' => 1,
                        'category_ids' => Array
                            (
                                '0' => 1,
                                '1' => 2,
                                '2' => 91,
                                '3' => 132,
                                '4' => 133
                            ),
                        'categories' => Array
                            (
                                '0' => 'Category',
                                '1' => 'Groceries',
                                '2' => 'Personal Care',
                                '3' => 'Oral Care',
                                '4' => 'Toothpaste'
                            )
                    ),
                    
            )
        )    
    );  

   $result = [];
   foreach($a1 as $data){       
    foreach($data['hits'] as $row){         
         $chunkedArray2 = array_chunk($row['category_ids'],count($row['categories']), true);
         foreach($row['categories'] as $key => $value) {
             $result[$value] = $key.'-'.$chunkedArray2[0][$key];
         }          
    }   
   }
     $fi = []; $i = 0;
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
     $ke = explode('-',$value)[0];
     $va_cat_id = explode('-',$value)[1];
    
        if($ke == 2){
        $fi[$i]['id'] =  ($ke == 2) ? $va_cat_id : '';
        $fi[$i]['name'] =  ($ke == 2) ? $key : '';   
        
        $fi[$i]['parent_category']['id'] =  ($ke == 2) ? $va_cat_id : '';
        $fi[$i]['parent_category']['name'] =  ($ke == 2) ? $key : '';
        
        $fi[$i]['sub_category'][$i]['id'] =  ($ke == 2) ? $va_cat_id : '';
        $fi[$i]['sub_category'][$i]['name'] =  ($ke == 2) ? $key : ''; 
        }
    
    
     $i++;
 }
```

My output:

```
   Array
  (
   [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1596
        [name] => Home & Kitchen
        [parent_category] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1596
                [name] => Home & Kitchen
            )

        [sub_category] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1596
                        [name] => Home & Kitchen
                    )

            )

    )

   [7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 91
        [name] => Personal Care
        [parent_category] => Array
            (
                [id] => 91
                [name] => Personal Care
            )

        [sub_category] => Array
            (
                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 91
                        [name] => Personal Care
                    )

            )

      )

  )
```

Expected output:

```
       Array
      (
       [0] => Array
        (
        [id] => 1596
        [name] => 'Home & Kitchen'
        [parent_category] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => 'Groceries'
            )
        [sub_categories] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 3820 
                        [name] => 'Stationery'
                        [sub_categories] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 3821
                                        [name] => 'Party Accessories'
                                    )
                            )
                ),
                [1] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 1597 
                        [name] => 'Kitchenware'
                        [sub_categories] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1598
                                        [name] => 'Cookware & Non Stick'
                                    )
                            )
                    )
             )
         )
       [1] => Array
        (
        [id] => 91
        [name] => 'Personal Care'
        [parent_category] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => 'Groceries'
            )
        [sub_categories] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 132 
                        [name] => 'Oral Care'
                        [sub_categories] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 133
                                        [name] => 'Toothpaste'
                                    )
                            )
                ),
                
            )
        )
      )
```

please check the above code and let me know.

Comment: I can vaguely understand the format that you are looking for, but it is highly specialized, to the point that I would question how it was generated in the first place. Is it possible to go to the source of this and deal with it there, instead of here. Also, it appears that the root item in your array is the third level, with the second item being flagged as the parent, and the fourth and subsequent all flagged as child siblings, is that right?

Comment: yes. correct. In first phase, can get the $a1 from third party lib.